# PrimeFaces Extensions: What type's can be used with DynaForm Control?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, types, controls, primefaces-extensions

We are using the DynaForm from PrimeFaces Extensions, it works wonderfully well so far.
I can't find a list of type's that are available with the DynaForm Control.

**What type's can be used with DynaForm Control?**

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it now. **You can actually add every type.**

**Map your *backingbean* type to your *page type*.**

```
DynaFormRow row;

row = model.createRegularRow();
row.addControl(new BookProperty("Field 1", true), "typetest01");

row = model.createRegularRow();
row.addControl(new BookProperty("Field 2", true), "typetest02");
```

Handle them like:

```
<pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{testSearchBacking.model}" var="data">

    <pe:dynaFormControl type="typetest01" for="txt">
        <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}" />
    </pe:dynaFormControl>

    <pe:dynaFormControl type="typetest02" for="txt">
        <p:outputLabel for="txt2" value="#{data.name}"/>
        <p:inputText id="txt2" value="#{data.value}" required="#{data.required}" />
    </pe:dynaFormControl>

</pe:dynaForm>
```

Hopefully, this will clear the clouds for other developers too! Cheers.